# Google ReCAPTCHA - JSON Syntax error returned for Verifying the user's response

Tags: php, json, post, recaptcha

I have a problem with the Google ReCAPTCHA.

After my form is posted (for the moment on the same page), when I check the `$_POST` var, I do not see a `$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']` in my POST values.

But when I check my network activity during validating the recaptcha, I see it's Posting a UserVerify to google, and here it's responding me this :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbKES.png]

JSON Syntax error with `)]}'` at the beginning.

I assume this is why I do not have the response in my POST, but I can't find why.

Comment: The response is valid, you can ignore warning from console. See a reason: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36862268/1586649

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.

With my differents includes, I didn't noticed that my Captcha HTML Code was **outside** my form, and this was problematic.