# reCaptcha invalid json response

Tags: recaptcha

Using the recaptcha javascript client ( http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=vcRecaptchaApiLoaded&render=explicit ) the automatic request (GET https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/userverify?k=XXXXXXXXX) after you select the correct images returns an invalid json which afterwards is sent to back to google and their json validation fails. This worked as expected for months now. Not anymore :(

Server side library used reCaptcha PHP (1.1)

Response

```
)]}'
["uvresp","03AHJ_Vuup5SJJ583dSIfezFl80dp2AlJ_rZpz3vqGWlOTmbjZqH8izwjruJASNhQI0tOOnmj2Pzg14xMw7dryeqVfTGhx6dg_x2i0PRA1ZeDyrBNn8DX-w5S262Zb3_ZWKj5JDBiqPVnXtNLGbyBxjd97VHanspJWU_-qKWLSWVKxLK6n3lm9Biw33oUCEiGA39GNa09Z6TSAEtnolQCf_LPPRWKoE_e50f2s5ZpUVG5GNVdX7qGBRwphTgcUhwOjA8uYTzmA9co3Jwk2KR5UQ0zzVRJzRZZTBuK9km3PE1WV05ACAwrJi29niDpVaRmpooAnIkHNgGyGBu7u3W7gU6YAHtwya8PYhdF__G_MMG8XpVFDTBa196hKD6hxw-E2PsxmoIQJrU1K89mmzNIh-xLNQ7KJvrBMzVf8A5FHyUQgL5UNDWVwSkWCdC_3swxBzi7R3p8VIrUtkIqJFA_GSAxy0cBRJ8J55Pfs5rzhfR8j-x1hGCzi_6vJrbrwfNesoLEB7GWJtElcljhBYvcDNzU_B_VJ7Sck-6i1Nd0qdmtSiCRZYNyaZ8uGLoDdNgCY-0Oi4802AlI26H7TjGBcKnr4gmaHXTNRf1W7x_3FV05DxVsTqeAlo8zGqmiVqcgmX64BbLK4fD9Xoait1_Lp5vK26fCaOQmGKF7CJaYPuxnX-zXgSkfZDCG6rs6xv1CfZQnIKD0W3Yz522VD4YdNfATb3FywhFWbZuxoBIt6vslZDlPXh2MYOkAmYfIPIo8WoWazMoLI_8iNBZPiMlRL0PS5aQiLSrvbf-sknMHhfM2MJYsfrQjC52aDRaHYdcZbY6Wxlhw0tQEknX8B47_DAQzCKkpoFsecO1eMHuInIykZ1l7TOdZMytI-NzGg21KeKAE8dK6ZWee0UEqDJvCkj5aH5TQcBA--ygbOS186bAptUP5n6WvORx1Nb2ZU_AF9fB23PJWH1xvB4gZoNDvhLmdpkE1Po9Lyim1P61E2rrgYjWgPRwT4jUo",1,120]
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [recaptcha gets invalid json from call to https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/userverify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35348234/recaptcha-gets-invalid-json-from-call-to-https-www-google-com-recaptcha-api2-u)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/36862268/2140017

And here is my answer from that link:

> Actually the value returned is not valid json but well parsed by the
>   Google's API.
>
> Is it a protection ? I don't know, but if you look at the javascript,
>   you can find that:
>
> ```
> var jm=function(a,b,c,d,e,g,h,l,r){this.xl=a;this.$c=c||"GET";this.Ka=d;this.Gg=e||null;this.Td=m(h)?h:1;this.ye=0;this.xh=this.Nh=!1;this.uh=b;this.Mh=g;this.md=l||"";this.Zb=!!r;this.Wf=null};f=jm.prototype;f.getUrl=function(){return this.xl};f.ug=function(){return this.$c};f.Ca=function(){return this.Ka};f.fi=function(){return this.Zb};f.bi=function(){return this.md};var nm=function(){G.call(this);this.nj=new hm(0,mm,1,10,5E3);H(this,this.nj);this.ad=0};x(nm,G);var mm=new Nh;nm.prototype.send=function(a){return new Lc(function(b,c){var d=String(this.ad++);this.nj.send(d,a.Uf.toString(),a.ug(),a.Ca(),mm,void 0,u(function(a,d){var h=d.target;if(Xk(h)){var l=a.ml;h.B?(h=h.B.responseText,0==h.indexOf(")]}'\n")&&(h=h.substring(5)),h=Hg(h)):h=void 0;b(new l(h))}else c(new om(a))},this,a))},this)};var om=function(a){y.call(this);this.request=a};x(om,y);
> ```
>
> especially take a look at:
>
> ```
> var l=a.ml;h.B?(h=h.B.responseText,0==h.indexOf(")]}'\n")&&(h=h.substring(5)),h=Hg(h)):h=void 0;`
> ```
>
> The parser explicitly checks that the value begins by `)]}` and strips
>   it.
>
> I suggest you to just apply the same substring on the *"json"* string

Comment: It is indeed a duplicate, I couldn't find it before I posted. I am just passing the json around I don't care that is not valid, but google does, lol.