# Invisible Google reCaptcha returns 410 when verifying user's input

Tags: recaptcha, invisible, invisible-recaptcha

We're using invisible reCaptcha and, once in a while, Google's Javascript code makes a request to Google's servers receiving a response status 410, instead of 200.

We don't have control over it as the request is being made by Google's reCaptcha Javascript code.

If the challenge has been presented to the user, the following is an example of what the failing request looks like:

```
GET https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/payload?c=03AOPBWq_EYB...
```

And the response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 410 Gone

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Gone</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Gone</H1>
<H2>Error 410</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

It fails about 10% of the time. Below is a "history" of HTTP requests:

Request #1

```
POST https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/reload?k=6LcqZCEU...
v:r20170515161201
reason:fi
bcr:[1943341955,-150...
...

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: application/json
...

)]}'
["rresp","03AOPBWq_EYBOYkGkn-1S...",null,600,["pmeta",null,null,null,
null,[[["TileSelectionStreetSign",null,3,4,4,null,null,[]
]
,["dress",null,3,4,4,null,null,[]
]
]
,[]
]
]
,"multicaptcha",null,
["bgdata","Ly93d3cuWk5rOHFMZDlvNDZFa..."]
]
```

The above response looks like invalid JSON but is expected as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35348234/recaptcha-gets-invalid-json-from-call-to-https-www-google-com-recaptcha-api2-u/36862268)

Request #2

```
GET https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/payload?c=03AOPBWq_EYBOYk...
...

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: image/jpeg
content-length: 50528
...

<JPEG>
```

Request #3

```
POST https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/replaceimage?k=6LcqZCEUAA...
v:r20170515161201
c:03AOPBWq_EYBOYkGkn-1SplFL...
ds:[[5,6,9,10,13,14]]

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: application/json
...

)]}'
["dresp","03AOPBWq-Iyck5GCpx86hk57XSxF-9b4GMaDeujP...",[]
,null,[]
]
```

Request #4 (the failing one)

```
GET https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/payload?c=03AOPBWq_EYBOYk...
...

HTTP/1.1 410 Gone
content-type: text/html
...

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Gone</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Gone</H1>
<H2>Error 410</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Just bumping this...

Comment: Have you ever managed to solve this? We are getting similar issue.

Comment: @proxiblue Nope, it was a long time ago but it was never solved :( I can't look back at it now ... different company

Answer (score 1):

This is basically because the session has expired. When ever you receive an **error 410** (i.e. not successful and you still wish to upload the file), you must start a new session. Please have a look at the below link for details :
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.9

Comment: Hi there, thanks, but how do I explain it if the requests are only a few seconds apart? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your call is `GET`. You need `POST`

Ref: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/payload?c=03AOPBWq_EYB..